# Installed rbenv and dugway but lost from there?

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-yosemite, rbenv

To cut a long story short this year I changed from PC to Mac and I've been asked to code a website for Big Cartel and I've an existing theme I'd like to edit.

Turns out getting dugway up and running on Mac isn't as straight forward as PC but none the less it has to be done.

I've got homebrew installed which allowed me to install rbenv along with the plugin.

From there I did the usual gem install dugway which went fine

But I'm confused why dugway create mytheme didn't work I got the error

-bash: dugway: command not found

I believe it's because I hadn't selected the directory but how do I do that?

Also does anyone know how dugway can unpack a theme downloaded?

Thanks

Comment: Getting 

configuration /Users/JamesMichael/.rbenv/config.ru not found

on dugway server?

Comment: "Getting" - when? What are you doing that causes this message?